# How to deal with Error: Unable to access jarfile - docker

Tags: java, docker, maven, jar

I'm new to docker and I struggle with **"Error: Unable to access jar file target/nbd.jar"**. My application is a CRUD api for cassandra cluster made with Springboot. I'm trying to execute `docker-compose up`. Every cassandra node is running, I only have problem with my API. I think the problem is with the Dockerfile, but I don't know how to solve it myself/ Tried different things but none of them worked.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim 
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY target/${JAR_FILE} target/nbd.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","nbd.jar"]
```

My filesystem (I cut everything but docker and target files):

```
├── docker
│   ├── docker-compose.yaml
│   └── Dockerfile
(...)
├── src
│   ├── (...)                 
├── stop_all.sh
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   (...)
    ├── generated-sources
    │   └── annotations
    ├── generated-test-sources
    │   └── test-annotations
    ├── nbd.jar
    └── test-classes
```

And my pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
   (...)

</project>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What value are you passing to `JAR_FILE` when you build the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You copy jar file from `target` directory on the local computer to the `target` directory inside a docker container. But then you didn't specify `target` directory in `ENTRYPOINT`. Simply put, docker can't find your jar file when it tries to start.

Try this:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim 
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY target/${JAR_FILE} nbd.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","nbd.jar"]
```

Comment: I tried this. I get a different error:
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile nbd.jar

Comment: First issue with accessing a jar file is solved. How did you get your jar file? There is something wrong with you jar file. If you will try to run it locally via command line. Does it work?

Comment: I created and built it using IntelliJ IDEA